# How to add custom html renderer in admin form

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform

How can I add custom html renderer for my for element.

I need a text bux besides it a button which will call ajax when clicking on it to do some random work. How can I implement it.

here is my form field

```
<fieldset name="General">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                    </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="product_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">product_name</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Import</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">product_name</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to magento sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sampleform_form.xml) you can set render following way:

```
<field name="color">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <!--component constructor-->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/js/form/element/color-select</item>
            <!--main template for form field that renders elementTmpl as a child template-->
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <!--customized form element template that will show colors-->
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/form/element/color-select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Autumn colors</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Following tag is responsible for custom template

```
<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/form/element/color-select</item>
```

Comment: hey tnx mate. I was trying the same thing just mismatched my file locations. Any ways as now we create grid from ui_component is it also necessary to create a form in similar way as for magento 2 future aspects ?

Comment: yes. of course.

Comment: @SohelRana Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/294109/68281