# Magento 2 : Add custom block in ui form field

Tags: magento2, ui-form, custom-field

I want to call custom block to call my custom `.phtml` in ui-form field.

How to do that?

My form field :

```
<field name="title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

I want to add this as html code (**Go to stores -> Attributes -> Product -> Edit attribute -> Manage Labels**):

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you want to archive??

Comment: I want to display this store labels in ui form field.

Comment: do you have screenshot?

Comment: Wait. I will give you within few minutes.

Comment: I added screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: Hey @Rakesh did you checked? Can you please help me.?

Comment: I will find the solution and update you

Comment: Did you found anything?

Comment: didn't get time to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Follow this below steps to store labels in ui form**

**1)** Add this container in your ui form inside fieldset :

```
<container name="group_title_container">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
         <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
         </item>
      </item>
   </argument>
   <htmlContent name="group_title">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group Title</item>
         </item>
      </argument>
      <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Custom</argument>
   </htmlContent>
</container>
```

Using this, you can add custom block in htmlContent

```
<argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Custom</argument>
```

2) Create **Custom.php** block file for call phtml file :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template {
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'custom.phtml';
}
```

**3)** Create **custom.phtml** file to create store label field :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/custom.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$stores = $storeManager->getStores(true, false);
?>
<label class="label admin__field-label" for="group_name" data-ui-id="adminhtml-form-renderer-fieldset-multistore-0-text-name-label"><span><?php echo __("Store Label") ?></span></label>
<div class="admin__field-control control">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-content in collapse" id="manage-store-labels">
        <fieldset class="admin__fieldset fieldset">
            <div class="admin__control-table-wrapper">
                <table class="admin__control-table" id="attribute-labels-table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($stores as $_store): ?>
                            <th class="col-store-view"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_store->getName() ?></th>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($stores as $_store): ?>
                            <td class="col-store-view">
                                <input class="input-text<?php if ($_store->getId() == \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID): ?> required-option<?php endif; ?>" type="text" name="frontend_label[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_store->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo "Test"; ?>"<?php if ($block->getReadOnly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?>/>
                            </td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

For proper layout, Add this below css code :

```
#manage-store-labels .admin__fieldset
        {
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
        }
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: this solution show html successfully, but it will render it outside of the fieldset and also can't catch it as a params in save action.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `htmlContent` element near you field inside a fieldset, but not inside the field because of the schema restrictions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="some_field" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Some Title</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <!-- Html conent (block) inside UI-form fieldset -->
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <block name="block_name_here" class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
        </htmlContent>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My dummy phtml-template (`Vendor_Module::test.phtml`):

```
<h3><?= __('Test Message');?></h3>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Elements which are available inside the `<field>` declared in the `vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd`:

```
<xs:group name="formElementsConfig">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="hidden" type="formElementHidden" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="file" type="formElementFile" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="input" type="formElementInput" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="date" type="formElementDate" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="boolean" type="formElementBoolean" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="checkbox" type="formElementCheckbox" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="checkboxset" type="formElementCheckboxset" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="email" type="formElementEmail" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="colorPicker" type="formElementColorPicker" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="select" type="formElementSelect" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="multiselect" type="formElementMultiselect" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="text" type="formElementText" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="textarea" type="formElementTextarea" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="price" type="formElementPrice" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="radioset" type="formElementRadioset" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="wysiwyg" type="formElementWysiwyg" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="fileUploader" type="formElementFileUploader" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="imageUploader" type="formElementImageUploader" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="button" type="formElementButton" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
```

Another way is write a custom component for the `input` field with a custom template, add some methods which could load custom controller with your block using ajax each time when it loaded. If you share your requirements in more details I will update my answer, if I can :)

Here is example:

Add inside ui-form new field:

```
<htmlContent name="example_title">
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">MageWorx\ShippingRules\Block\Adminhtml\Shippingrules\Carrier\Edit\Tab\ExampleTitle</argument>
</htmlContent>
```

Create corresponding block:

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingRules/Block/Adminhtml/Shippingrules/Carrier/Edit/Tab/ExampleTitle.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\ShippingRules\Block\Adminhtml\Shippingrules\Carrier\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

/**
 * Class ExampleTitle
 */
class ExampleTitle extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'MageWorx_ShippingRules::example_title.phtml';

    /**
     * Use your ui-form name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dataFormPart = 'mageworx_shippingrules_carrier_form';

    /**
     * Use your data source name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $source = 'carrier';

    /**
     * Retrieve stores collection with default store
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection
     */
    public function getStores()
    {
        if (!$this->hasStores()) {
            $this->setData('stores', $this->_storeManager->getStores());
        }
        return $this->_getData('stores');
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValues(): array
    {
        // Next part of data must be obtained from your object!
        // Data exist as an example
        $values = [
            0 => 'Main Title'
        ];
        // Next part of data must be obtained from your object!
        // Data exist as an example
        $storeValues = [
            1 => 'Label One',
            3 => 'Label Three',
        ];

        foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
            if ($store->getId() != 0) {
                $values[$store->getId()] = isset($storeValues[$store->getId()]) ? $storeValues[$store->getId()] : '';
            }
        }

        return $values;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDataFormPart(): string
    {
        return $this->dataFormPart;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource(): string
    {
        return $this->source;
    }
}
```

and template:

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingRules/view/adminhtml/templates/example_title.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \MageWorx\ShippingRules\Block\Adminhtml\Shippingrules\Carrier\Edit\Tab\ExampleTitle $block */
?>
<?php

use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

?>
<div class="admin__field-control">
    <table class="admin__field-control admin__control-table" id="attribute-labels-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-store-view"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Main Value (Admin)')); ?></th>
            <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $store): ?>
                <th class="col-store-view"><?= $block->escapeHtml($store->getName()); ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php $titles = $block->getValues(); ?>
            <td class="col-store-view">
                <input class="admin__control-text input-text required-option"
                       type="text"
                       data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDataFormPart())?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getSource());?>[example_title][<?= /* @noEscape */
                       (string)Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID ?>]"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($titles[Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID] ?? '') ?>"
                />
            </td>
            <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $store): ?>
                <td class="col-store-view">
                    <input class="admin__control-text input-text<?php if ($store->getId(
                        ) == Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID): ?> required-option<?php endif; ?>"
                           type="text"
                           data-form-part="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDataFormPart())?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getSource());?>[example_title][<?= /* @noEscape */
                           $store->getId() ?>]"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($titles[$store->getId()]) ?>"
                        <?php if ($block->getReadOnly()): ?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?>
                    />
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Do not forget to change the `protected $dataFormPart = 'mageworx_shippingrules_carrier_form';` and `protected $source = 'carrier';` according your ui-form settings. Implement method which load data from a model.

Field on the form will be looking like this:

[image: form example with new fields]

Data could be obtained from the post in your controller:

[image: request headers]

[image: post data in controller xdebug]

Comment: Yes. That's i know about that. It will add direct in fieldset. But, i want to set in field. How to do that?

Comment: @Niket what kind of block you are using? Which data stored inside?

Comment: From block, i just want to call phtml. Nothing else.

Comment: Go to store -> All Products -> Products -> Edit any attribute and go to second tab.

Comment: I want to that store labels grid in ui form field.

Comment: @Niket seems like much easiest way is to move the main field in to `.phtml` and render just only `blockHtml` having all fields (main + store labels).

Comment: Can you please add that code in answer?

Comment: @Niket I've updated my answer, but don't know is it exactly what you need. Anyway main idea will be clear. In case you need additional help please, leave a comment.

Comment: Yes. I got it like this as like your ss. But, i want to display with label. Same as like your "Carrier code" field. Then how to do that?

Comment: @Niket It's pretty simple: just add another `<input>` with name `carrier_code` or other to the template. But some css rules will be needed to make it look good.

Comment: I did. But, it's not display label. I want same as like display in my second screenshot.

Comment: @Niket Sure, as I said it need some css magic to make it suitable.

Comment: It's not done. Can you please provide full solutions? I m new in Magento so. Please help me. It means a lot for me.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, I follow your flow, but HTML content form  fields not posted, pls check with this link   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318983/magento-2-html-content-form-not-posted-admin-ui-form     suggest me what I did wrong