# Magento 2: Html Content Form Not Posted Admin Ui Form

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

we are trying to create an admin UI From with Html content with Field Set, Html Content input fields are posted.

**what I did:**

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/page_master_add_form.xml`

```
<fieldset name="campaignpages">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Page</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
       <field name="cam_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Code</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">pages</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <container name="lead_service_section">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Campaign\Edit\Services\ServicesData</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
        <field name="cam_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">pages</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
</fieldset>
```

Find My Block File :

`Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Pages\Edit\Services\ServicesData`

```
class ServicesData extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_module::service/servicesdata.phtml';


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Template File:

`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/service/servicesdata.phtml`

```
<div class="services">
        <div class="add_services">
            <button type="button" id="add_service"> + Add Services</button>
        </div>
        <div class="new_services">
            <div class="admin__field-control" id="add_new_services">
                <div class="services" data-sku="">
                    <table class="admin__field-control admin__control-table" id="attribute-labels-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-store-view"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SP Code')); ?></th>
                                <th class="col-store-view"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')); ?></th>
                                <th class="col-store-view"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("")); ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-store-view">
                                    <input data-form-part="page_master_add_form" type="text" name="spcodes" class="admin__control-text input-text required-option" value="10000">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-store-view">
                                    <button type="button" class="get_services_data">Submit</button>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-store-view">
                                    <button type="button" class="get_services_data">Remove</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

In that form render correctly, But while post the form, its not only post the HTML content input fields.

Let me know, what did wrong.

Reference:

[image]